# Can't download the laravel installer using composer, can't connect to the symfony repo

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to download the laravel 5.3 installer via composer (in windows 10) as the official documentation says, but when i execute this command in the console

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

after a while i get this:

```
Using version ^1.3 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.1.7)
    Loading from cache
    Failed to download symfony/process from dist: Invalid argument (C:\Users\Nicolßs\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor/symfony/process/510d7cdfaba888079a59ff4e97c9d707)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.1.7)
    Cloning 66de154ae86b1a07001da9fbffd620206e4faf94 from cache

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/symfony/process.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.
  - https://github.com/symfony/process.git
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\Nicol├ís\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\process'...
    "git-upload-pack 'C:/Users/Nicol├ís/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/https---github.com-symfony-process.git'": git-upload-pack 'C:/Users/Nicol├ís/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/https---github.com-s

  ymfony-process.git': No such file or directory
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  - git@github.com:symfony/process.git
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\Nicol├ís\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\process'...
    Host key verification failed.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Aparently, i can't clone the symfony/process repo. But then i try to do that manually with gitclone and i can connect and clone the repo perfectly.

Please help.

---

References
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3

Answer (score 0):

If what your aim to do is develop with laravel. Get this tool: laragon at https://laragon.org/
It makes laravel development on windows cool.

Comment: that doesn't really solve the problem, but it's a different approach, thanks

Comment: Yes, it's a different approach. Welcome.